# Fast method for PyMongo Cursor to array/DataFrame

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, numpy

I am fetching 43k records with just 2 datetime fields from my mongoDB server. It takes me around 10 seconds to 20 seconds to convert the cursor to array to dataframe. I have tried variety of ways to do this:

Attempt-1

```
docs=pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find({"dId":4},{"ts":1,"cd":1,"_id":0}).sort("ts",-1).limit(43200)))
```

Attempt-2

```
docs=collection.find({"dId":4},{"ts":1,"cd":1,"_id":0}).sort("ts",-1).limit(43200)
ts = np.empty([2,43200], dtype='datetime64[us]')
for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
    ts[0][i] = doc["ts"]
    ts[1][i] = doc["cd"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ts']=ts[0]
df['cd']=ts[1]
```

Attempt-3

```
docs=collection.find({"dId":4},{"ts":1,"cd":1,"_id":0}).sort("ts",-1).limit(43200)
arr= [x for x in docs]
```

Attempt-4

```
my_data = list(map(lambda x: list(x.values()), collection.find({"dId":4},{"ts":1,"cd":1,"_id":0}).sort("ts",-1).limit(43200)))
result=np.array(my_data)
```

How to reduce this time to less than 2 seconds?

Comment: I would start by asking how your indexes are ? At least to make sure it is not taking time while finding, sorting the result.

Comment: @user3375448 I have indexes on dId and ts. The time to fetch from the database is around 300 milliseconds. From what I could see major portion of the time goes into the for loop.